# XmlMapper: Force entity encoding of > to &gt;

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm using XmlMapper to migrate some XML feed logic from Ruby to Java. One of the diffs I got is the following:

Old output (from Ruby code):

```
<qualification>· Development experience in one or more object-oriented programming languages&lt;br/&gt;</qualification>
```

New Output (from XmlMapper.writeValueAsString):

```
<qualification>· Development experience in one or more object-oriented programming languages&lt;br/></qualification>
```

Note the `<br/>` tag in the new output, where the `>` character is not encoded to `&gt;`. I realize this is not technically required per XML Specification, but in my case it's a strict requirement due to the way a 3rd-party consumer is handling my data. Is there an easy way to enable XmlMapper to do this?

Comment: Well, we always tell people they should be using a real XML parser, not some hand-crafted approximation. You should tell your 3rd party consumer the same thing. XML is about standards: if you don't follow the standards, you don't get the benefits.